# Substitute results to an error with cor.test

Tags: r, correlation

I am trying to write a loop, which returns linear regression and correlation parameters. When trying to pass substitute through `cor.test` function, I encounter an unexpected error

```
data(iris)
i <- 1
vars <- list(par = as.name(colnames(iris)[1]), expl = as.name(colnames(iris)[2:4][i]))
lm(substitute(par ~ expl, vars), data = iris) # works
lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = iris) # works. Result equal to the statement above

cor.test(~Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width, data = iris) # works
cor.test(substitute(~par + expl, vars), data = iris) # does not work
## Error in cor.test.default(substitute(~par + expl, vars), data = iris) :  
## argument "y" is missing, with no default
```

To my understanding the cor.test statement should be the same than the manually inputted one.

What is the reason for the error? How can I write a substitute statement for `cor.test` that works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error stems from the fact that the first version is of `formula` type and the second one is `language`:

```
str(substitute(~par + expl, vars))
# language ~Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width
str(~Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width)
# Class 'formula'  language ~Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width
# ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

If you use `as.formula` on the second version it works:

```
cor.test(as.formula(substitute(~par + expl, vars)), data = iris)
# Pearson's product-moment correlation
# 
# data:  Sepal.Length and Sepal.Width
# t = -1.4403, df = 148, p-value = 0.1519
# alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
# 95 percent confidence interval:
# -0.27269325  0.04351158
# sample estimates:
# cor 
# -0.1175698
```